# Session still available even after deleting from database in flask

Tags: python, flask

I have created a flask application there is `session` for each user.

- Once `user` submit the data entry will be inserted to MySQL database
- User can click on the `output` button to fetch the details of `user` that entered

My Problem statement

- I have deleted from data base `delete from the log`
- While refreshing the web page still `the reports are showing`. ?
- I have printed `cursor.execute(select * from log where user='user')` the entries are available, it should not be there

What I tried?

I have tried `session.clear()` then its not saving anything

Comment: Can you try a CTRL-F5 to hard refresh the browser?

Comment: @mechanical_meat  tried bro

Comment: Can you show the actual DELETE statement? Maybe there is something wrong with it.

Comment: no i have checked after deleting i have checked select * from log

Comment: Have you tried deleting the migration directory as well as the alembic column in your database if you have any